# How to use @Facet with embedded entities?

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm trying to upgrade from HS 4 to 5 but I'm having trouble with faceted searches. I understand that @Facet needs to be added on the faceted fields and have seen [this](http://in.relation.to/2015/05/11/hibernate-search-530-beta-1-with-native-lucene-faceting/), for example. But the faceted field I want to use is embedded 2 levels down and all I get is this error:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000268: Facet request 'ClientId' tries to facet on  field 'scan.clientGroup.id' which either does not exist or is not configured for faceting (via @Facet). Check your configuration.
```

I've tried @Facet in the embedded entity in many different flavours but nothing seems to work - I'd like to know how this is meant to be set up, thanks.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search are you using exactly? Could you please show us the code of your entities (with the Hibernate Search annotations)?

Comment: I'm using all the latest: hibernate 5.4.1, HS 5.11.1, lucene 5.5.5. I've created a minimal project here: https://github.com/grommitz/hibernatesearch5-faceting  - 2 simple entities - Parent & Child. I want to search the children by name grouping them by the parent.id. Simply adding @Facet on Parent.id doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you mentioned in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54889338/6692043) is correct.

Another solution would be to have an `@IndexedEmbedded` from child to parent, add the `@Facet` directly on the parent id property, and use `parent.parentId` as a field name in your faceting request, as demonstrated in [the PR I just sent](https://github.com/grommitz/hibernatesearch5-faceting/pull/1/).

The main advantage of your solution is that, if `Parent` is itself indexed (if it has an index of its own), parent's index won't be polluted with the faceting field unnecessarily (on contrary to my solution).

The main drawback of your solution is that you essentially declare an indexed field on a transient field in your entity (transient in the JPA sense, i.e. not mapped to a database column directly). This means Hibernate Search is not able to determine when that value will change, and as a result Hibernate Search will disable some optimizations and will reindex the `Child` entity whenever a property of `Child` changes, *any* property, even unrelated.
If your entity is small, rarely updated, or has a limited number of instances, this might not matter, however. Just keep that in mind if you notice a lot of database reads for seemingly no reason in the future.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do the PR and for the explanation, that is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. I have no idea if this is the recommended way, perhaps @yrodiere could comment?

Basically just add a getter method on the root entity with the relevant @Facet annotation:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Child {

...

    @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
    Parent parent;

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    @Facet(encoding = FacetEncodingType.STRING)
    public Long getParentId() {
        return parent != null ? parent.getId() : null;
    }
}
```

then in the query:

```
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery);

        FacetingRequest facetingRequest = builder.facet()
                .name("facetRequest")
                .onField("parentId")
                .discrete()
                .orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.COUNT_DESC)
                .includeZeroCounts(false)
                .maxFacetCount(10)
                .createFacetingRequest();

        FacetManager facetManager = fullTextQuery.getFacetManager();
        facetManager.enableFaceting(facetingRequest);

        List<Facet> facets = facetManager.getFacets("facetRequest");
```

In this case I also had to encode the field as a string to allow discrete faceting to be used, as opposed to range, because it is a numeric field by default.